# C++ SFML Sprite Losing Data

Tags: c++, sfml, loss

I have two classes in my WIP Tetris clone, and one is instantly called by the main function. The .h and .cpp files for this class are here: http://pastebin.com/mDMeqMfV

The second class which the first class has an instance of, can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wG2b0whL The commented section is a set of colors I'm using as overlays to make different colored blocks. Anyway, the problem I'm having is in the instance of the Block class. Despite in the initialize function setting the position of the sprite to the variable position, the sprite does not actually render there. It seems to default to 0, 0 by the time it gets to the Draw function, and will not go to its proper position even when calling the setPosition function as seen in the Draw method. Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have two comments here (that won't solve your issue, though). First, gist.github.com is nice to share code – you can put serveral files together unlike on pastbin. Second, **don't** put everything in your constructor. What you did in `PentrisGame` means you won't be able to use virtual functions. Instead, add a `run()` method or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Block b as a member of your class but you have constructed a new one in the constructor of PentrisGame. Perhaps you forgot to do an assignment? As it stands that one you constructed is destroyed and your member is left in its default state.

Comment: So instead of using Block b(...) and using b = Block(...) would fix the problem?

Comment: That was the problem. I was doing the same thing in the Block class. Thanks for the help!